Set cursor to a line instead of a block, in terminal insert mode?
In terminal insert mode, the cursor is a block while its a line in (regular) insert mode. I looked through :h guicursor and while it lists command-line insert mode, it doesn't say anything about terminal mode (:term).

Could you share with us which OS you are using (e.g. Linux, macOS, Windows)?

macOS and Neovide

The cursor shape in terminal mode is depending on the cursor shape of the underlying terminal window.
The following question gives you more information about how to control it on Linux.
